# Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) Count Unique Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to make a Visual Basic Macro to count unique items in a row without doing the copy and pasting and data remove duplicates.

For some reason I'm having issues with my syntax. When I run the script it outputs with the number of rows.

This is my first time programming in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).

```
Private Sub FrequencyCount_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim outcell As Range
    Dim outnum As Integer
    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    Dim ArrayLength As Integer
    Dim unique As Boolean

    Dim i
    outnum = 0
    ArrayLength = 1
    unique = False

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range to Count Uniques", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    Set outcell = Application.InputBox("Select an Output Box for Uniques", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)


    For Each B In rng.Rows

        If outnum = 0 Then
            ReDim MyArray(1)
            MyArray(ArrayLength) = B.Value
            outnum = outnum + 1
            ArrayLength = ArrayLength + 1

        Else

           i = 0
           unique = True
           Do Until i < ArrayLength


              If MyArray(i) = B.Value Then
                  unique = False

              End If
              i = i + 1

           Loop
            MsgBox unique
            If unique = True Then
                ReDim Preserve MyArray(0 To ArrayLength + 1)
                MyArray(ArrayLength) = B.Value
                ArrayLength = ArrayLength + 1
                outnum = outnum + 1
            End If

        End If

        Next


    End

outcell.Value = outnum

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at using the `Dictionary` data structure for VBA, it should make this solution easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are setting i = 0 then saying

```
Do until i < arraylength`
```

Well if i = 0 then it will always be less than arraylength, this probably should be

```
Do until i > arraylength
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Well worth taking a look at @ShrivallabhaRedij answer.  Very compact and neat.

Answer (score 4):

It is generally considered bad practice to ReDim Arrays in Loop and not recommended. If you search internet then many discussions like this will come up
[ReDim in Loop](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?450819-Is-it-bad-or-slow-to-use-Redim-Preserve-many-many-many-times)

You can use built-in functionality to get where you want. Example code which should work for you.

```
    Sub FrequencyCount_Click()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim outcell As Range

        Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range to Count Uniques", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
        Set outcell = Application.InputBox("Select an Output Box for Uniques", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

        rng.Copy outcell.Cells(1, 1)
        outcell.Resize(rng.Cells.Count, 1).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
    End Sub
```

Comment: Damn, didn't think of using `RemoveDuplicates` that way.  Good answer. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank you. Your solution will help with large datasets as Dictionary tends to be faster side.

Answer (score 2):

As @RyanWildry suggests, you can use the Dictionary object for this.

The code to call the procedure will also define the range containing the duplicates and the start range to paste the unique values to:

```
Sub Test()

    'This will take values in the first range and paste the uniques starting at the second range cell.
    'NB:  Search for With...End With.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        FrequencyCount .Range("B2:B48"), .Range("D2")
    End With

End Sub
```

This code will then place the values into a dictionary, which also removes any duplicates and then uses a couple of techniques to paste back into rows or columns.
I've added lots of comments and this link may help for further reading on the Dictionary object:  https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

```
Public Sub FrequencyCount(SourceRange As Range, TargetRange As Range)

    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim vArr As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    oDict.comparemode = vbTextCompare 'Non-case sensitive.  Use vbBinaryCompare to make case sensitive.

    'Go through each cell in the source range and copy the value to the dictionary.
    For Each rCell In SourceRange
        'Change the value in the dictionary referenced by key value.
        'If key value doesn't exist create it.
        oDict(rCell.Value) = rCell.Value
    Next rCell

    'Paste in rows.
    x = 1
    ReDim vArr(1 To oDict.Count)
    For Each vKey In oDict.Keys
        vArr(x) = oDict(vKey)
        x = x + 1
    Next vKey
    TargetRange.Resize(UBound(vArr)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vArr)

    'Paste in columns.
    TargetRange.Resize(1, UBound(Application.Transpose(oDict.Keys))) = oDict.Keys

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an more compact solution, I cobbled together from other solutions.

```
Sub UniqueCountinSelection()

   Dim outcell As Range
   Dim itms As Object, c As Range, k, tmp As String

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range to Count Uniques", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    Set outcell = Application.InputBox("Select an Output Box for Uniques", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    Set itms = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng
        tmp = Trim(c.Value) 'removes leading and trailing spaces
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then itms(tmp) = itms(tmp) + 1
    Next c
outcell.Value = UBound(itms.Keys) + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: How does this evaluate for dupes?  Does it enter each of the items as a key and therefore dupes can't be added?  Does this work for non-numeric values?

Comment: I tested this on these data points, It evaluated correctly and I believe since it is using the keys, it doesn't add dupicates
1,250.99

1,250.99
Test
Test
2,229.81
3,513.27
4,764.26
N/A
69.242
69.242